# Node.js SDK for PayPal API - Invalid Resource ID While Trying to Create and Execute Payment

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

I attempting to use Node.js PayPal SDK to execute a basic PayPal payment. I am trying to use the "Express Checkout" flow.

On my client-side page, I have the following code:

```
           <div id="paypal-button"></div>

<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function() {
            return paypal.request.post("/Checkout/checkout").then(function(data) {
              console.log("I returned!" + data.id);
                return data.id;
            });
        },

            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
return paypal.request.post("/Checkout/confirmation", {
    paymentID: data.id,
    payerID: data.payerID}).then(function() {
        window.location("/Checkout/Success");
    });        
}
                   }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
```

The "Checkout" controller (I am using Sails.js) is as follows:

```
var paypal = require("paypal-rest-sdk");
require("../../config/paypal_config.js");
module.exports = {

    addCart: function(req, res) {
        var items = [];
        var listingID = req.param("id");
        var cartID;

        if (req.cookies.cart == {} || req.cookies.cart == null) { // cart is not set
            // Create cart in DB and in Session
            Cart.create().exec((err, cart) => {
                res.cookie("cart", cart.cartID);
                cartID = cart.cartID;
            });
        } else { // retrieve existing cart using session cookie
            cartID = req.cookies.cart;
        }
        // Add items to cart and recalculate total
        CartItem.create({ quantity: req.param("quan"), listing: listingID, cart: cartID, unitPrice: req.param("unitPrice") }).exec((err, result) => {
            if (!err) {
                return res.redirect("/checkout/cart");
            } else {
                console.log("Error - " + err);
            }
        });

    },

    // read cart, display total, prepare transaction details for PayPal
    cart: function(req, res) {
        return res.view("checkout/cart");
        /*  var cartItems = req.cookies.cart.items;
          CartService.getCartView(cartItems, function(err, results) {
              if (!err) {
                  return res.view("checkout/cart", { items: results });
              }
          });*/

    },

    checkout: function(req, res) {
        Cart.findOne({ cartID: req.cookies.cart }).populate("cartItems").exec( function(err, cart) {
            if (!err) {
                     console.log(cart);
                cart.updateCart();
                cart.save();
                var jsonTran = cart.returnTransactionJSON();
                paypal.payment.create(jsonTran, function(err, payment)  {
if(err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    } else {

console.log("This is the payment.");
      return res.send(payment);
                           }                
                    });
            }
        });
    },

    cancel: function(req, res) {
        return view("checkout/cancel")
    },


    confirmation: function(req, res) {
        var paymentID = req.query.paymentID;
        var payerID = { payer_id: req.query.PayerID };

        paypal.payment.execute(paymentID, payerID, (err, payment) => {
            if (!err && payment.status == "approved") {
                console.log("Payment completed!");
                return view("checkout/confimation");
            } else {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        })
    }

};
```

The paypal_config.js file is as follows:

```
    var paypal = require("paypal-rest-sdk");

paypal.configure({
    "mode": "sandbox",
    "client_id": "MYCLIENTKEY",
    "client_secret": "MYSECRETKEY"
})
```

I am able to log-in with my test account; however, whenever I click the "Pay Now" button, the window simply stays on the "Processing..." screen and I receive the following error:

```
  This is the payment. // logged from my code above
'{"Authorization":"Bearer A21AAHQU9emmuxBOevEsdGWl2NcE_gnz7rMARxbPVF6fW7LlZW8mCkzpv8ra5pBpQGRcxKJ95nuos7t6ITJxdY
m_b63Yx374Q","Content-Length":2,"Accept":"application/json","Content-Type":"application/json","PayPal-Request-Id
":"d19c6ac5-cd3e-428b-aa9d-4f7d34b6c013","User-Agent":"PayPalSDK/PayPal-node-SDK 1.7.1 (node v6.11.0-x64-linux;
OpenSSL 1.0.2k)"}'
'{}'
paypal-debug-id: a7c118ac9eb71, a7c118ac9eb71
'{"date":"Tue, 04 Jul 2017 00:34:26 GMT","server":"Apache","paypal-debug-id":"a7c118ac9eb71, a7c118ac9eb71","con
tent-language":"*","connection":"close","set-cookie":["X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%
26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D2464307801%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3D; Expires=Tue, 04 Jul 2017 01:04:26 GMT; do
main=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly","X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT"],"vary":"Auth
orization","content-length":"204","content-type":"application/json"}'
'{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found.","information_link":"https://deve
loper.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"a7c118ac9eb71"}'
{"response":{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found.","information_link":"h
ttps://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"a7c118ac9eb71","httpSta
tusCode":404},"response_stringified":"{\"name\":\"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID\",\"message\":\"Requested resource ID was
not found.\",\"information_link\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID
\",\"debug_id\":\"a7c118ac9eb71\",\"httpStatusCode\":404}","httpStatusCode":404}
```

and my client code logs the following:

```
I returned!PAY-14496911M2734903LLFNOF4Q
```

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Appears a few people have had the same issue, not sure if you can find something on here that might help you https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/330 **OR** https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/issues/188

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: Very welcome, I hope you can find some help from one of those. I haven't used paypal with `node.js` yet so other then my comment above I can't offer any further help :(